# Default Back Button Text and Font Setting

Tags: ios, swift2, uibarbuttonitem, back-button, navigationbar

By default, Navigation back button text comes as previous screen title or <

I am trying to change that to just <=|

But Its coming as shown in the picture
[BackButton Image.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bovLt.jpg)
So, I want to know how to change its font to make big <=| and remove the default <

I tried

Tried the same code in viewDidLoad of first start screen,
So i also want to know where to place this code:

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool)
{
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem?.title = "<=|"
    let FntStgVal = [NSFontAttributeName:UIFont.systemFontOfSize(50, weight: UIFontWeightLight)]
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem?.setTitleTextAttributes(FntStgVal, forState: .Normal)
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your code in `viewDidLoad` like this.

```
class BaseViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    func setNavigationWithCustomBackButton() {
        let btnLeft:UIButton! = UIButton(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 20, 16))
        btnLeft.setTitle("<=|", forState: .Normal)
        btnLeft.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.systemFontOfSize(19, weight: UIFontWeightLight)
        btnLeft!.addTarget(self, action: "handleBack:",forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
        let leftItem:UIBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(customView: btnLeft!)
        self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = leftItem
    }

    func handleBack(sender: UIButton) {
        self.navigationController?.popViewControllerAnimated(true)
    }
}
```

Now use this `BaseViewController` as parent of your all `viewController` and call its method in `viewDidLoad` like this.

```
class ViewController1: BaseViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.setNavigationWithCustomBackButton()
    }
}
```

Now it will add custom back button in your `NavigationBar`. 
Hope this will help you.

Comment: I want to change that back button through out the app, and action: "handleBack:" does not do default back button function

Comment: `handleBack` is the custom `Action`. If you want this through out the app then create `BaseViewController` and assign this `BaseViewController` as parent of all your `viewController`.

Comment: Have you got what i say or should i edit my answer to explain you?

Comment: I dint get ur answer, can u explain a bit more..
.
Also i am new to stackoverflow. I do not have enough 15 reputations to vote for ur ans, so kindly vote my question up so u too can vote for you

Comment: I have edited answer. Please check that. Create something like this it will solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks for the solution.
Am new to stackoverflow and do not have enough reputations yet, So kindly vote for my question up, so i can vote for your ans