# Swift: Set "Back" as default button text to "segue back" button

Tags: ios, swift, localization

I'm looking for a way to set all back button texts to "back" instead of it by default showing the title of the view the segue came from.

I have multiple views and segues and hope there is a cleaner method than to use PrepareForSegue in all the view controllers.

This would simplify localization as well since I am giving the users the ability to change the language.

Anyone have any suggestions or solutions?

Comment: You should take a look at this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38049389/default-back-button-text-and-font-setting

Answer (score 1):

Create extension to UIViewController (You can create different empty file for this, and make sure to import UIKIt)-:

```
import UIKit
extension UIViewController  {


    func leftBarButton(subView:UIView,labelView:UILabel,imageView:UIImageView) -> UIBarButtonItem{

        let leftBarButton = UIBarButtonItem(customView: subView)
        subView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 40)
        subView.addSubview(imageView)
        subView.addSubview(labelView)

        imageView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: subView.leftAnchor,constant: -8).isActive = true
        imageView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: subView.topAnchor, constant: 2).isActive = true
        imageView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 30).isActive = true
        imageView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 30).isActive = true

        labelView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: imageView.rightAnchor,constant: 8).isActive  = true
        labelView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: subView.rightAnchor).isActive = true
        labelView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: subView.topAnchor).isActive = true
        labelView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 40).isActive = true

        return leftBarButton
    }

    func anotherMethod(){
       _ =  self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
    }
}
```

In controller class -:

```
  var views : UIView = {
        let subView = UIView()
        //subView.backgroundColor = UIColor.green
        return subView
    }()

    var imageView : UIImageView = {
        var view = UIImageView()
        view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.image = UIImage(named: "Back")
        return view
    }()

    var labelView: UILabel = {
        var labeView = UILabel()
        labeView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        labeView.text = "Back"
        labeView.textColor = UIColor.blue
        return labeView
    }()

    // ViewDidLoad
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        //self.navigationBar.tintColor = UIColor.green
       self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = leftBarButton(subView: views, labelView: labelView, imageView: imageView)


    }
```

Comment: This works, but it removes the arrow on the left side of the text.

Comment: @Gjeruldsen For that you have to modify things accordingly, what you need to do is add UIview as subview inside bar button , then add back button image and label inside view.

Comment: @Gjeruldsen I have updated answer of how to add custom Back Button and Image.Please check now.

Answer (score 0):

Since there's no appearance proxy for what you need, you could go inheritance route and create a base class like this:

```
class BaseClass: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Back", style: .plain, target: nil, action: nil)
    }
}
```

and just inherit from it:

```
class YourViewController: BaseClass { ... }
```